# Copy text inside <pre> tag from HTML to a string variable using Python

Tags: python, text, tags, copy

I'm trying to scrape a webpage response, using python, but ran into a problem. In this case, the webpage that I want, give me an output response (which is json text) and it's inside a pre-tag like this:

```
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"WANTED TEXT AS JSON TEXT"}
    </pre>
```

i did this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "urlforwantedwebpage"  (THIS URL IS DIFERENTE EVERY TIME I RUN A SEARCH BUT THATS NOT A PROBLEM)

data = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
t = soup.find_all('pre')

print(t)
```

but the output that i receive is: [ ]

Can someone help me?

Comment: have you checked whether you are grtting the correct data? `data.content`?

Comment: Yes if i print data.content the wanted text is there

Comment: ‘To scrap’ means to throw away, to discard. You should use scrape (and scraped, scraping)

Answer (score 0):

Executing

```
data = requests.get(url)
```

returns a Reponse object.

You need to pass the html text to Beautifulsoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
```

Print both `data` and `data.text` to see the difference.

Comment: I have data.text in my code but forgot to put in here in this question. The problem persists.

Comment: Is the Response object a valid one? Does the html text contain the elements you are trying to find?

Comment: Don't know if is valid. i think so. the value that i get when print(data.content) its the text (Json) like this one:        {"result":"check","message":"Message in this place. ","nif_validation":true}

Comment: As read in the documentation, "*Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.*" So you can't use BeautifulSoup to analyze a page that returns a JSON object.